# xsp/apache not working for ASP.NET application, xsp4 from terminal does work

Tags: apache, mono, mod-mono, xsp

I have a site make in monodevelop on Archlinux.

The site runs fine in monodevelop F5 run, and also runs fine when running xsp4 from the terminal

However, when running under apache, I am getting errors, specifically:

```
Method not found: 'System.Type.op_Equality'.

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type.op_Equality'.
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Importantly, I can replicate the error by running plain xsp from the terminal, rather than xsp4 that works

My next (hopefully logical :p) thinking is that I need to somehow tell apache/mod_mono to use xsp4

Please help me figure this out! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up `MonoServerPath` to `mod-mono-server4` in your config. (Just like it was done [here](http://buddylindsey.com/how-to-get-asp-net-mvc-2-working-with-mono-in-10-steps/) on this [screenshot](http://buddylindsey.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/vhost.png)).

Comment: Thank you! With a bit of brain-wracking, I got this going.. appreciate it.